# TypeError: this.element.down(...) is undefined - Timeframe.js and Prototype

Tags: javascript, prototypejs, typeerror

I am currently using a JS script called [Timeframe.js](http://stephencelis.github.com/timeframe/) with the [Prototype](http://prototypejs.org/) javascript framework, to create a calendar widget. In my local copy it works great, however in my staging environment I am getting the following javascript error:

> TypeError: this.element.down(...) is undefined
>
> this.element.down('div#' + this.element.id + '_container').insert(calendar);

The error is referring to line 97 in timeframe.js library file. It is a part of the following method:

```
// Scaffolding
createCalendar: function() {
  var calendar = new Element('table', {
    id: this.element.id + '_calendar_' + this.calendars.length, border: 0, cellspacing: 0, cellpadding: 5
  });
  calendar.insert(new Element('caption'));
  var head = new Element('thead');
  var row = new Element('tr');
  this.weekdayNames.length.times(function(column) {
    var weekday = this.weekdayNames[(column + this.weekOffset) % 7];
    var cell = new Element('th', { scope: 'col', abbr: weekday }).update(weekday.substring(0,3));
    row.insert(cell);
  }.bind(this));
  head.insert(row);
  calendar.insert(head);
  var body = new Element('tbody');
  (6).times(function(rowNumber) {
    var row = new Element('tr');
    this.weekdayNames.length.times(function(column) {
      var cell = new Element('td');
      row.insert(cell);
    });
    body.insert(row);
  }.bind(this));
  calendar.insert(body);
  this.element.down('div#' + this.element.id + '_container').insert(calendar);
  this.calendars.push(calendar);
  this.months = this.calendars.length;
  return this;
},
```

I've also verified that the contents of this.element.id are valid. The value ends up being 'div#calendars_container' which is an element that exists within the markup, so it's not missing from the DOM.

I've been unable to determine the root of this issue, I've ensured I have the latest version of Prototype and Timeframe but the error still occurs. I've been using these scripts in this way for some time now and haven't run into this before now, can anyone put me on the right track?

Comment: As @VeXii says we need to know what `this` refers to - please edit your question with the code containing the line that is giving you the error to give us context. Thanks!

Comment: Updated my code with the specific method where the error is thrown.

Comment: according to the script `div#calendars_container` gets created at line 59 and inserted into the parent element. Can you confirm that `div#calendars` is the parent of `div#calendars_container` in your rendered HTML?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to share a little more context to get this resolved, I think. If the code runs fine locally but not on your (presumably off-site) staging environment, then it could be a matter of not all of your code being loaded by the time execution reaches the line in question.

I appears that your snippet is inside an event handler; even if all your code is loaded prior to reaching this line, perhaps a timing issue exists where Prototype hasn't yet extended the `this.element` object with the `down()` function?

Most likely the greater latency between your staging environment is causing some network-bound function to execute after another, in a way opposite to how it routinely does it for you locally.

Put a breakpoint on this line and see what happens.